# MS SQL explicitly using "default defaults" on NOT NULL fields - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I stumbled upon this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.whatever (
  [flBlahBlah]  BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
  [txCity]      NVARCHAR (50) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
  [cdFrom]      VARCHAR (10)  DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL
);
```

I can't think of a reason to add those default values. Not null string is defaulted to `''` and bit is defaulted to `0`. Is there a reason for defining these default values? Am I missing something? Is this in some best practice handbook I'm not aware of?

I'd just use:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.whatever (
  [flBlahBlah]  BIT           NOT NULL,
  [txCity]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  [cdFrom]      VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL
);
```

The database is in MS SQL Server 2012, now migrating to Azure Database.

Comment: Because a `VARCHAR NOT NULL` does not have a default of `''`.  If you don't specify a value for a `NOT NULL` field, it throws an error.  There is no system default.

Comment: What do you mean "default defaults"? There are no defaults unless you choose to select some. If someone does `INSERT whatever(txCity) values ('hello');`, that will work with version 1, but not with your version without the defaults.

Comment: If you try to insert a row into that table without specifying a value for a column you will be prevented. There is no automagic default value if you don't explicitly specify one.

Comment: @Siyual Shame on me, sorry. Don't know why I believed there was a system default. (Actually I do know why, too much VB.net mutilated my brain.)

Comment: I guess I should just delete the question, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you create table from a first batch of your question. Then insert value like this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.whatever (flBlahBlah) VALUES (1)
```

You will get 1 row `dbo.whatever`

```
flBlahBlah  txCity  cdFrom
1
```

So if you "forget" to insert in one of the column with default values determined - SQL Server will take care of them.

It is very useful when you got table, in which you need to insert new field. With default value determined you don't need to change SP/query's/other stuff that works with this table.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I thought that this would happen without default values too. Now I know better.

Comment: My pleasure! I need to add that if you determine NULL or NOT NULL for column, it just tells server if NULL value is allowed in that column, and default value is pasted only if determined for that column and not inserted in query. Also '' is not equal to NULL, it only means that value is empty, NULL means there is no any value.